# Ajax get jquery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, get

I'm trying to send an ajax request by get through jquery
data is dynamic, when it have many items I get the following error:

> The head of the requirement is very large

How can I solve that?
there is a limit characters for these requests?

Comment: That doesn't look like a browser error message, it looks like something being returned by the API you're calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's **not** any structural limits on GET request length. However there are limits on your **server configuration, sometimes web apps, client browser** that specify how long a GET request can be!

> Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy implementations might not properly support these lengths.

So if your GET request is longer than **255 bytes**, It's advised to use POST requests instead.